# window.print() problems in Dynamics CRM 2011 forms

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

We've been implementing a Dynamics CRM 2011 solution where one of the requirements was to print out a bespoke-styled form containing sub-grids and charts. The short story is that clicking on a "print" link (which calls the `window.print()` method) throws up a series of JavaScript errors. These, however, are non-fatal and clicking through each will allow the form to be printed OK.

> Line: 73 
> Char: 24234 
> Error: The value of the property 'isNull' is null or undefined, not a Function object.
> URL: https:://aks7.crm4.dynamics.com/_static/_forms/controls/img.lu.htc?ver=-115872263
>
> (note that the double colon above was intentional!)

One of our early thoughts was that the problem was down to unsupported customisations, so as a test I created a new entity with a basic form. On the ribbon I added a print button which calls the `window.print()` method. The result is exactly the same. I've also replicated the issue on CRM Online.

The upshot is that either using `window.print()` is unsupported, or we've found a bug or both. Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that it's unsupported since the native print functionality renders a different page before sending to print (suggesting that this is a workaround for some feature of their `.htc` files).

Can you not take the same approach? The stub URL for the "Print Preview" is at `.../_forms/print/print.aspx?allsubgridspages=true&formid=<form-guid>&id=%7b<record-guid>%7d&objectType=<object-type-code>`. You could wrap this is a HTML web resource and call the CRM print button function from your HTML holding frame.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the window.print, you have to automate the print preview.

I use this, but it's unsupported:

```
parent.document.getElementById('Mscrm.Jewel-Default').children[0].click();
parent.document.getElementById('Mscrm.Jewel.PrintPreview-Menu16').click();
```

http://blog.customereffective.com/blog/2011/08/printing-in-crm-2011.html